# Does this 1978 code for a 6800 really clear ALL of memory?

Tags: assembly, 6800

On page 43 of the October 1978 Dr. Dobb's Journal (reprinted in [Volume 3 Page 425 Issue 10 Number 29](https://archive.org/details/dr_dobbs_journal_vol_03/page/n426/mode/1up?view=theater)) is a letter to the editor giving three 6800 routines to clear ALL of memory, stating...

```
  Routine 1 (8 bytes): fill memory with NOPs. Properly
assembled, this routine will execute anywhere in memory.
    
2000 8E 20 03       LDS  #STACK
2003 86 01    STACK LDAA #NOP
2005 36       PUSH  PSHA
2006 20 FD          BRA  PUSH

  Routine 2 (5 bytes): fill memory with zeroes. This routine
must reside at the addresses shown, and assumes that executing
an opcode of zero is identical to executing an NOP.
    
FFFB 8E FF FD      LDS #HERE-1
FFFE 8D FE    HERE BSR HERE

  Routine 3 (8 bytes): fill memory with ones (all bits on).
This routine must reside at the addresses shown.

FFF7 8E FF FA       LDS #THERE
FFFA CE FF FF THERE LDX #HERE+2
FFFD 8D FE    HERE  BSR HERE

  Assuming that every location in the address space acts
like RAM (ie, can be read, written, and executed), then all
three routines fill ALL of memory, obliterating themselves
in the process.
```

Can anyone confirm this code really works as advertised, given the stated constraints?

---

*(The Letter itself is a comment to an 8080 memory clear routine in DDJ of [September 1976 Page 32](https://archive.org/details/dr_dobbs_journal_vol_01/page/n260/mode/1up?view=theater), left column, all the way down)*

Comment: I touched up the assembly for you here because `PUSH` at address 2005 is a label, and so it belongs in the other column

Comment: Routine 1 seems to rely on the fact that you can use a mnemonic as an immediate (the #NOP) - That's actually not a very common feature.

Comment: @tofro, it could have been defined further up in the listing

Comment: @Lorraine wasn't, see the [linked source material](https://archive.org/details/dr_dobbs_journal_vol_03/page/n426/mode/1up?view=theater). But since the letter just shows off the routines itself, the author might have believed that constant to be obvious.

Comment: What's might be more interesting to today's readers than that little NOP trick is the reasoning for the original 8080 routine: _"the program will infinitely loop, writing zero into the same memory location. The lights on your computer will indicate when the program has stopped;"_. A feature that can only be understood with a front panel computers in mind - less common nowadays :))

Comment: Oh my, a real-world [imp](https://vyznev.net/corewar/guide.html#start_imp), what fun!

Comment: For what it's worth, around that time, I took a "Mini-Computer Survey" class.  We looked at 4 machine architectures and instruction sets (PDP-11, Data General Nova and two others, IIRC).  Clearing memory on each machine was one of the assignments, with honorable mention bestowed to the smallest program. The trick is that you have to make sure your program is still running when the last few bytes are cleared. I think the DG Nova (with its weird addressing mode) could be done in an insanely small program (say 8-12 instructions (each 2-byte). This kind of program was a thing to do back in the day

Comment: @tofro, you could just use `LDA #1` instead. Everyone worth their salt back in the days would know this was a 6800 `NOP` off the top of their head :-)

Comment: Back in the day, kids would go into computer stores and enter these kinds of  programs to get the machine into a locked up state.

Answer (score 12):

Assuming the address space of the CPU is 100% writeable (i.e. no ROM somewhere), these routines seem in fact to clear all of the memory (including the routines themselves) to either zero or the opcode of NOP (01) by using the stack. They are, however, a bit of an academic nature - once the memory is completely filled, the CPU will be executing NOPs (or #0s) from the freshly cleared memory, without any possibility to escape.

All the routines seem to be relying on the fact that the stack pointer is expected to wrap around to $FFFF when it is at 0 and something is pushed. By exploiting this wrap-around, they clear the memory "behind" the routines and the routines themselves.

The tricky part of all routines is when the wrapped-around stack starts to "nibble" at code at the end of the routines: In routine 1, at some point the code at $2006 will change to

```
   BRA 1
```

which will jump into the series of NOPs already created, run through roughly 64k of NOPs (with the PC wrapping around) and do that several times until the PSH A is executed for the last time, replacing it with a NOP.

You might wonder why in routine 3, the X register is loaded with $FFFF: That is because on the last loop, the BSR HERE will overwrite itself with $FFFF, which is the instruction "STX $FFFF" - and fill the last bytes in memory from the X register.

None of the routines is, however, particularly useful. Once the RAM is set to the desired value, we've arrived in a dead end. Considering that contemporary computers often had a switch panel with single-step and HALT functionality, you could assume a bit more usefulness (you could stop the CPU looping through 64k of NOPS manually and enter new code - but that would assume some sort of banking mechanism to bank in some ROM for support)

Comment: I'd say the usefulness seems obvious - at least in back then mindset of programmers believing they create the most sought after product in the universe and want to protect it against 'piracy'. By pointing monitor/break vectors to this routine an attempt to inspect the code will delete the code.  [ I'll take that 'back then' back - people arestill the same, just the machines more complex :) ]

Comment: @Raffzahn If "destructive" is considered "useful" as in your example, then yes :)

Comment: It's a use case - of course usefulness of that case is in the eye of the beholder :))

Comment: @raffzahn Well, if my goal would be to protect my code, I would rather overwrite memory with something that *looks like* reasonable code, but isn't, than with NOPs. But I'm a terrible character, I admit :)

Comment: That's all Greek to me anyway. Coming from a mindset before micros, I never really understood why anyone would want such in the first place. And even if he would, being from engineering I never would waste time with protection schemes as they all fail eventually.

Comment: @Raffzahn: I was thinking they'd be more useful as a means of initializing the state of all memory on a ROM-less system with a toggle-switch-based monitor, which would be likely to have RAM mapped to all addresses (though perhaps ignoring the upper address bits.

Comment: It may not just protect code but also data. Maybe even a requirement from the client to leave no traces of behind after the program processed top secret data. Today this might be the requirement for programs like password managers.

Comment: @BlackJack: unlikely.  If you're processing sensitive data, you want to limit the places it can get copied in the first place, and that also means you only need to scrub those places.  The machine code for the memory-zeroing function is one part of memory that definitely doesn't have to get overwritten if you're just worried about overwriting sensitive data.

Comment: @BlackJack going by the letters written (see the links added to the question) it seems clear that it's more about being some code golf challenge than any real use case.

Comment: @Raffzahn "Code golf" as done here on the CG SE network would be a descendent/relative of hacking in the 1960s-1990s. Hacking was a challenge sport, sometimes done solo to learn new things, and often done between friends, computer science organizations, etc. Trying to figure out how to clear every byte of memory back then would definitely have been a puzzle, because the hardware wasn't designed to allow that directly. They were meant to encourage scientific methods and learning.

Comment: @phyrfox Oh, is that what we did back then? Sounds cool.

Answer (score 6):

The simple way to "confirm" those would be to find a 6800 emulator with debugger, load those snippets and execute them.

But just looking at them, I can explain how they should work, so I'd *assume* they should do what they said they would do (unless I am overlooking something). All of them use the 16-bit stack pointer S.

```
2000 8E 20 03         LDS  #STACK
2003 86 01      STACK LDAA #NOP
2005 36         PUSH  PSHA
2006 20 FD            BRA  PUSH
```

Point S to STACK, then load the opcode for NOP into A, then keep pushing it (wrapping around the 64K) until it overwrites the BRA, at which point execution will continue at 2009 (which doesn't help, because it has been overwritten). This will actually not clean the complete memory, but leave the loop of the code snippet intact (which is acceptable).

```
FFFB 8E FF FD        LDS #HERE-1
FFFE 8D FE      HERE BSR HERE
```

Do a subroutine call to HERE (which loops), pushing the return address, which happens to be 0000 for the code at this location. Finally it will overwrite the BSR with 00 00, execute those as NOPs, and continue to address 0000 (which again doesn't help, as it has been overwritten).

```
FFF7 8E FF FA         LDS #THERE
FFFA CE FF FF   THERE LDX #HERE+2
FFFD 8D FE      HERE  BSR HERE
```

Same idea, but the return address is FFFF, and the LDX acts as a nop already having FF FF as the operand.

Comment: I'm pretty sure once the BRA PUSH is partially overwritten, it will change into BRA 1, (thus jump into NOPs already created), run through alll these until $FFFF, PC would wrap around and run into the code yet again (Assuming "everywhere is RAM"). That will continue until everything is set to NOP - Admittedly, it is pretty unlikely we'll find an implementation that has 100% RAM.

Comment: I also started to write an answer, but took too long to write it. Basically yes the routines write all the memory, except for the parts it doesn't because the routines stop working after being slowly overwritten so they can't erase the parts that are left because there are no longer opcodes left to overwrite anything. And one of the routines has a pretty bold assumption that undefined opcode 00h is executed as a NOP so there goes that too.

Comment: @justme On a 6309, which is largely compatible with the 6800, for example, the opcode $00 will negate the accumulator. Not a NOP, but doesn't hurt execution. $9D and $DD are, however, not a good idea for known reasons (HCF). Actually, some of the routines work pretty reliable even overwriting their own code completely if you assume all RAM and use wrap-around in both SP and PC.

Comment: I must take my words back. All the code snippets manage to fully end up with the memory contents set to constant 01h, 00h, or FFh values by writing all the memory, except routine 1 does not write address 2004h which is already 01h and routine 3 does not write addresses FFFBh and FFFCh which are already FFh. The assumption that 00H is NOP instead of random invalid opcode must be made, but it could do anything.

Answer (score 2):

The code works as advertised, let's examine each piece of code in (what some may call excruciating) detail, covering the "phases" in which it runs :-)

---

For the first code segment (at *any* `base` address):

```
base+0 8E 20 03       LDS  #STACK
base+3 86 01    STACK LDAA #NOP
base+5 36       PUSH  PSHA
base+6 20 FD          BRA  PUSH
```

The phases are:

- Executing the code from `base+0` up to but not including `base+5` (the `PSHA`). This code sets up the stack pointer and accumulator to perform the work in a loop, and no memory has yet been changed.
- The loop starts, and this loop only needs addresses `base+5`, through `base+7` inclusive to be preserved. It places `NOP` into all memory locations from `base+3` down to `0000` (`base+4` already *had* a `NOP`).
- The stack pointer wraps to `ffff` and we continue writing `NOP` bytes down to `base+8`. At this point, *all* of memory is `NOP` except for the `PSHA` and `BRA PUSH` instructions.
- Now it gets a little tricky. The next `PSHA` replaces the offset of the `BRA` instruction with `NOP` which turns it into a `BRA 1` instruction. When it executes *that* instruction, it no longer goes to the `PUSH` label but instead jumps a forward a little into the memory that contains all `NOP` instructions.
- It will continue executing each instruction, wrapping from `ffff` to `0000` and then executing the `NOP`s before `base+5`.
- Executing the `PSHA` at `base+5` will then replace the first byte (opcode) of the `BRA` instruction with `NOP` and it will then start executing the `NOP`s again (the *entire* `BRA PUSH` is now two `NOP` instructions).
- It will once again go through all of the `NOP` memory, wrapping at `ffff`, until it once again reaches the `PSHA`. That instruction is the final nail in the coffin as *all* memory is now filled with `NOP` instructions. It will happily execute those instructions (wrapping and wrapping) until the heat death of the universe, assuming the CPU and power supply last that long.

---

The next one relies heavily on the code location because the return address is important:

```
FFFB 8E FF FD      LDS #HERE-1
FFFE 8D FE    HERE BSR HERE
```

In sequence:

- Execution of the first instruction sets the stack pointer to `fffd`. Note that the stack pointer in the `6800` is the first *free* location.
- The first `BSR` will push the return address on the stack then jump back to `fffe`. This return address is the address immediately past the `BSR` instruction, which is location `0000`. This is written to memory locations `fffc/fffd`.
- The second execution of that `BSR` will do exactly the same thing but the `0000` return address is written to `fffa/fffb` (note that the first of each of these pairs is even).
- This continues up until the point that `0000/0001` is overwritten by the `0000` return address and the stack pointer becomes `ffff`.
- The next `BSR` execution will push `0000` to memory locations `fffe/ffff`, effectively filling the last bit of memory with zeros, and overwriting the `BSR HERE` instruction in the process.
- Then, as in the first example (assuming as the question states that the invalid `00` opcode is identical to `NOP`), it will run forever.

---

The final example is a variation on the second:

```
FFF7 8E FF FA       LDS #THERE
FFFA CE FF FF THERE LDX #HERE+2
FFFD 8D FE    HERE  BSR HERE
```

The sequence of events in this example are as follows:

- It has to first load `fffa` into the stack and `ffff` into the `X` register.
- The first `BSR` pushes the return address `ffff` into memory locations `fff9/fffa` and adjusts the stack pointer down two to `fff8`. Like the previous example, `fffb/fffc` are both already `ff`.
- This continues to the point where all memory from `0001` to `fffc` is set to `ff`, and the stack pointer is `0000`.
- The next `BSR` instruction sets memory locations `ffff/0000` (because of wrapping) both to `ff` and sets the stack pointer to `fffd`.
- The `BSR` then executes one last time, pushing `ffff` to memory locations `fffd/fffe`, overwriting the BSR instruction. All of memory is now set to `ff` and the program counter is `fffd` (the `BSR` was actioned).

As in both other cases, the code will run then forever, wrapping at the `ffff/0000` boundary. Because memory is *filled* with `ff` bytes, the instructions executed are:

```
xxxx FF FF FF      STX $FFFF
```

This is the extended addressing mode `STX` which will get the two byte address at address `ffff/0000` (which is, of course, `ffff`). It will then store the `X` register (which is *also* `ffff`) into that address. Hence no memory is changed by this instruction.